# Jacop, constraint solver

Tags: constraints, solver, jacop

I am a beginner in Jacop constraint solver. I looked into its documents but couldn't find how to solve my following problem. I have a `matrix[n][n]` of `nxn` domain variables of `IntVar`. Now, I need to apply the following constraint to it:

`matrix[matrix[i][j]][k] == x`

Here `x` is a regular integer, I mean not domain variable.
The problem that i am facing is that `matrix[i][j]` is a domain variable, and I am unable to give it as the first index in `matrix[index][k]` again.
I will really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use element constraints to do that. First, create a vector matrix_k that represent a column k of matrix. Then, you can use Element constraint of the form Element(matrix[i][j], matrix_k, x).